# Python consecutive "with open"s not writing on second file open

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a list of dictionaries and write the values to a text file. In my code, the first "with open" that writes to "blockchain.txt" works fine, but the second "with open" that writes to "mining_queue.txt" does not work. It does not throw an error, it just fails to write. For context, to make the nested loop loop at all, I put an empty dictionary in the mining_queue list that is being looped through. Could that cause it to fail writing the rest of the content even if there is more full dictionaries afterwards? (I did also try to filter any empty dictionary from even executing the second loop).

My code:

```
def make_file():
    with open("blockchain.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in blockchain:
            for j in i.values():
                f.write(str(j) + " ")
            f.write("\n")
    with open("mining_queue.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in mining_queue:
            for j in i.values():
                f.write(str(j) + " ")
            f.write("\n")
```

("blockchain" and "mining_queue" are both lists that are filled/to be filled with dictionaries)

**My question: Why isn't the second "with open" writing anything to "mining_queue.txt"?**

**Edit:** It doesn't write anything when the loop hits a full dict either. (for more context)

**Edit, cont.:** Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import hashlib
import time
from multiprocessing import Value, Process


blockchain = [{"send": "0000000000000000", "receive": "0000000000000001", "amount": 10, "time": time.time(), "verify": hashlib.sha256((str(time.time()) + "asdsadaosidoa09").encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest(), "last_key": 10, "key": 10}]
mining_queue = [{}]

def make_file():
    with open("blockchain.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in blockchain:
            for j in i.values():
                f.write(str(j) + " ")
            f.write("\n")
    with open("mining_queue.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in mining_queue:
            for j in i.values():
                f.write(str(j) + " ")
            f.write("\n")

mining_queue.append(blockchain[0])

def loop(x):
    while True:
        make_file()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop_on = Value("b", True)
    p = Process(target=loop, args=(loop_on,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This is essentially the exact same as my full source code, but with all of the other unneeded backend stripped away. The results of running for at least 10 seconds are:
"blockchain.txt":
0000000000000000 0000000000000001 10 1621218521.4516537 48418cfdc364ed3f8750fa33d40c7be8c59a964635852089c5c65e7841a2f53f 10 10

"mining_queue.txt":
**completely empty here**

This makes me think that it is the multiprocessing.
How can I use the lists of items from the original process and not the new one?

Comment: If `mining_queue` just has an empty dict, your inner for loop won't run -- there are no values to loop over, which means there will be no writes. What do you expect to be in that file after not writing anything?

Comment: @Mark I don't expect it to write anything with an empty dict. My problem is that it doesn't write anything even if I know that the loop hits a full dict. I don't think that I added that in my question so my bad.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made an example that others could run, which reproduces the problem. Otherwise all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: ... Which is to say, a proper [mre] would hardcode a non-empty dict.

Comment: [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) suggests that `mining_queue` is empty, even though you insist it isn't.

Comment: @Mark When trying to reproduce it, it works fine, which makes me think that it could be the fact that the "make_file" function is being run from a different process due to multiprocessing. Could it be that make_file only remembers what "mining_queue" got initialized as because it is running from a different process?

Comment: If you have two processes writing the same file, whichever one finishes last will overwrite the results from the first.

Comment: If you have two processes, they don't share the same variables. So if process 1 adds to `mining_queue` dictionary, and process 2 runs `make_file` function, the latter won't write anything.

Comment: Put `print(mining_queue)` before the loop to see what's in the dictionary.